# url-rewriting and rss feed (feedburner) issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, rss, url-rewriting, feed

I am using below rule to read the URL like

URL:
**http://www.example.com/blog/sampe-post-title/10004/**

RULE:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ $1/details.asp?mod_id=$3 [NS,I]
```

Everything was fine untill I discovered that links coming via feedburner are not working anymore. Because feedburner adds some extra parameter to URL for stats/tracking etc.

For example **www.example.com/blog/sampe-post-title/10004/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed:+somesite+(my+feed)**

My rewrite URL doesn't recognizes the above URL anymore. Any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a rule for the feedburner URLs:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/\?(.*)$ $1/details.asp?mod_id=$3&$4 [NS,I]
```

I added an extra RegEx group at the end to capture everything after the question mark and place it after `mod_id`.  You could probably combine this with your other URL if you only wanted to have one rule for some reason, but you might as well just have two.

Comment: The URL query is not part of the URL path. So you can’t test it with the `RewriteRule` as it only operates on the URL path. You need the `RewriteCond` directive to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *QSA* flag to get the original requested URL query automatically appended to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the answer on my own: just replace the ending `$` with `.*` That's it!

Here is the modified rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/.* $1/details.asp?mod_id=$3 [NS,I]
```